# pandas read parquet with struct (not array)

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

A call to

```
pd.read_parquet('foo.parquet')
```

fails with:

```
ArrowInvalid: Chunked field reads not yet supported with StructArray
```

whereas
spark.read.parquet('foo.parquet').printSchema()
works just fine.

NOTE: it does not contain any arrays just a simple struct:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 ...
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar: double (nullable = true)
 |-- bar: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baz: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar: double (nullable = true)
```

Is there a way to still be able to read the struct in pandas without resorting to spark?

## edit

This is related to https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3058 
However, I am already using the latest 0.12 release and still face this issue.